# in the ionic hardware back button is not working when i have implemented facebook and google authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

**hardware back button is not working in ionic 5 angular because of google and facebook authentication **

**I tried all google auth and facebook auth in npm module but didn't get any error even app is installed but not opening what is the issue i don't konw**

> why the issue is come i don't know but when i comment google and facebook authentication, hardware back button is working whenever i uncomment all commented code hardware back button is not working even i tried all my exception.

*please give me the solution*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
Also Share your Code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.